# Cannot access web pages after PLESK update

Tags: apache, http, plesk

After upgrading Plesk to 12.0.18 (I'm using CentOS 6.6) I cannot access anymore to my HTTP server (apache) on port 80. I can access to the web page on the virtualhost port where it is configured (7080). Before the upgrade everithings worked nice and I could access to the web page on port 80.

I have already checked the firewall and it is disabled.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is already solved: [Plesk nginx port 80 no working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32444946/plesk-nginx-port-80-no-working)

You need to enable nginx again and start it.